# Fedora make command broken, kernel mismatch

Tags: linux, fedora, wifi, make

On a new Dell Inspiron 3521, I tried installing Linux. First try was Ubuntu, but couldn't get the WiFi working. After trying all sort of things and commands, some errors started to show. I then installed Fedora to check it out and see if it would pick up the WiFi. But it didn't either.

Now, I want to install some drivers that should fix it. I've extracted a tarball. The directory contains a Makefile, but when I run make, the following error is thrown:

```
KBUILD_NOPEDANTIC=1 make -C /lib/modules/`uname -r`/build M=`pwd`
make: *** /lib/modules/3.11.10-301.fc20.x86_64/build: No such file or directory.  Stop.
make: *** [all] Error 2
```

Now I tried to see if that `build` directory exists, and it does, but as a symlink to a directory that does not exist. It points to `/usr/src/kernels/3.11.10-301.fc20.x86_64`.

In the `kernels` directory, I only have `3.12.6-300.fc20.x86_64`.

Comment: Did you install the kernel headers?

Comment: Yes, `yum list | grep kernel-headers` outputs `kernel-headers.x86_64 3.12.6-300.fc20`

Comment: Turns out now I'm facing the exact same problem, but with a fc19 virtual machine. Let us hope for an answer.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Do `ln -s /usr/src/kernels/3.12.6-300.fc20.x86_64 /usr/src/kernels/3.11.10-301.fc20.x86_64`.

Comment: Thanks! That is actually what I tried before, but more out of a guess.. `make` still fails due to `implicit declaration of function` and `dereferencing pointer to incomplete type` errors.. I guess that is another problem then?

Comment: Then you did wrong! This is actually the last resource bullet, and not the first way of working around your problem. In fact it may be better to fail at this stage than going through and experience instability later.

Answer (score 0):

At least on fedora 20, this resolves the issue for me:

```
yum -y install kernel-devel-3.11.10-301.fc20.x86_64 kernel-headers-3.11.10-301.fc20.x86_64
```

If you're explicit with the header install, this solves the issue for me.